# Usage of "For your information" in a formal email

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, formality, phrase-usage

I am writing an Email to a professor and want to assure him I will refer to his publication in the future. I am just curious whether using "For your information" in the following sentence is right or not. Is there a better replacement that I can use for delivering my intention.

"For your information, Any future publication will be surely referred to your method and paper."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just say what you mean? You want to assure him that you will refer to his publication in the future. The active voice emphasizes that promise, not  *publication will be...referred*. Your commitment is not the passing mention of FYI.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, I want to assure him that I will refer to his publication in the future, as you said. Is there a better way to convey my intention?

Comment: Can you show us the first-person version, starting with *I can assure you*?

Comment: Ever hear *Say what you mean, mean what you say, and don't say it mean*? Once you find a simple way to say what you want, stop looking for other ways. Fancier is not only not better, it has already gotten you in trouble by hurting your promise with complicated words.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, Absolutely. It sounds very good. Thanks so much.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It was a great piece of advice that I will try to keep it in mind forever. Thanks so much and best wishes.